# Looking for Honda SPDIF connector information

Tags: connector, identification

Does anybody know what this connector is and perhaps where to find one?  It's used on a 2016 Honda Civic carrying SPDIF.  It goes into a plastic connector.  It has a metal tube and pin that goes inside the tube so it's a male connector goes into a female connection on the radio.  The scale is in cm.

[image: photo of connector part 1]

[image: photo of connector part 2]

[image]

[image]

Comment: please include a picture of the radio connector

Comment: I've included two more pics.  Top pic shows the female connector on the radio and I'm looking for the connector similar to the one showed on the bottom picture.